# Where to translate form field labels in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, translation, django-i18n

I am working on getting my site translations up to speed and I have got `.po/.mo` files working with all of my `{% trans %}` tags in my template, but I cannot figure out how to get my forms to translate well. The fields do not show up in my .po files...

app/forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as trans

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True, label=trans(u'Subject'))
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, label=trans(u'Name'))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label=trans(u'Email'))
    content = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea, label=trans(u'Content'))
```

I'm not sure what else I need to include here, please let me know if I need something else. I've tried to run

```
django-admin makemessages -l lang
```

but it doesn't populate with those fields

Comment: try use `python manage.py makemessages -l` not `django-admin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use `trans` as a alias for marking strings that need to be translated. You must use either the original name of the function or `_`. E.g.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
_('Subject') # this string will be marked for translation
```

or

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
ugettext_lazy('Subject') # this string will be marked for translation
```

**Edit**

Django uses `xgettext` behind the scenes for `makemessages`, and has a very specific list of keywords it picks up for translation:

```
--keyword=gettext_noop
--keyword=gettext_lazy
--keyword=ngettext_lazy:1,2
--keyword=ugettext_noop
--keyword=ugettext_lazy
--keyword=ungettext_lazy:1,2
--keyword=pgettext:1c,2
--keyword=npgettext:1c,2,3
--keyword=pgettext_lazy:1c,2
--keyword=npgettext_lazy:1c,2,3
```

Have a look at line 489 and onwards at https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py

Answer (score 1):

You should use [gettext_lazy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) as `_` or as so instead of `tran` which doesn't work as shown below. *`_` is recommended:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class ContactForm(forms.Form):                   # ↓ Here
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True, label=_('Subject'))
    ...
```

Or:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy

class ContactForm(forms.Form):                   # ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True, label=gettext_lazy('Subject'))
    ...
```